# How to add secret logging functionality to app in android

Tags: android, logging

I want to add a secret logging toggle switch so that when the QA guys here test the app, they should be able to do some magic secret trick which will switch on the logging for them onltytheir phones.

Magic secret trick meaning something like clicking on a few parts of the screen should switch it on or something else you suggest. This secret should be known only to the QA team and this should not affect the app in any other way.

I am planning to log the statements in a file on sd card.

What are your thoughts? What's the best way to do it?

What's the usual way of doing it?

Comment: Do your want to log your Application bug in a file or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way would be checking if a file (empty one, doesn't matter) exists on the sdcard. You could make the filename dynamic (based on date/month) or very obscure.

Answer (score 3):

Make a build for QA with logging on, turn it off for production. Avoid magic tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to not hide the functionality and just put a button (e.g. in your about box) that will enabled logging. Then if you have a problem at a customer site, that you have a hard time reproducing, you also have the possibility of having the customer sending you a log.

Otherwise I would also suggest checking for some magic file on the sd-card (e.g. app-xyz-enable-log) and if that exists you would automatically start logging to that sd-card. All your QA people would then make a empty file on their sd-card with that name prior to running your app.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do it (other than having separate builds) is to use the standard Android logging. You can teach your QA guys to extract the LogCat logs or build a small script for them to do so. Then when you log, make sure to log only the level necessary. For example:

```
private static String LOG_TAG = "MyLogTag";
private static boolean D = Log.isLoggable(LOG_TAG, Log.DEBUG);

...

if (D) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Something happened that I want to log!");
}
```

Then normally that statement won't log, but if you want to turn it on, you can run:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.MyLogTag DEBUG
```